# Buscador que no tenga en cuenta los acentos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un buscador en vivo, pero me gustaría que no tuviese en cuenta los acentos, dado que puede ser un problema. Me podeis ayudar, no se como gestionar esto. Gracias

**INPUT:**

```
<input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca tu prueba...">
```

**HTML DONDE BUSCA:**

```
<div id="contenedor" class="container row padPruebas">
    <?php
       $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM analisis");
       foreach ($results as $tipos){
      ?>

        <div class="col-12 center datos padceroZ">
          <div class="col-12 fondoPruebas34506">


            <!--<div class="divider902"></div>-->
            <!--<div class="txtPruebas22 center"><?php echo substr($tipos['strporque'], 0, 160) ?></div>-->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-5 col-md-4 col-xl-5">
                <h4><?php echo $tipos['strnombre'] ?></h4>
                <div class="txtPruebas2289 hidden-md-down"><?php echo substr($tipos['strconocido'], 0, 160) ?></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm-down">
                <div class="neceAyuno">¿NECESITA AYUNO?</div>
                <?php if ($tipos['ayuno'] == 0) {
                  echo "<div class=\"ayuno ayuno90\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i> Ayuno no necesario</div>";
                  }else {
                  echo "<div class=\"ayuno ayuno90\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i> Si ayuno</div>";
                  }
                ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm-down">
                <div class="neceAyuno">TIPO MUESTRA</div>
                <div class="cardat90">
                  <?php
                    if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 0) echo "<img src='images/svg/drop2.svg' alt='' class='orina331'>";
                    if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 1) echo "<img src='images/svg/orinaTA.svg' alt='' class='orina331'>";
                    if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 2) echo "<img src='images/svg/orisan2.svg' alt='' class='orina3390'>";
                    if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 3) echo "<img src='images/svg/pelo.svg' alt='' class='orina331'>";
                    if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 4) echo "<img src='images/svg/baston23.svg' alt='' class='orina331'>";
                    if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 5) echo "<img src='images/svg/baston23.svg' alt='' class='orina331'>";
                  ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-xl-1">
                <div class="neceAyuno">PRECIO</div>
                <div class="fondoPruebas34506h8"><?php echo $tipos['strprecio']; ?>€</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3 col-md-2 col-xl-2">
                <div class="verPrueba896">
                  <a href="especifica.php?ID=<?php echo $tipos['id'] ?>">VER PRUEBA</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="margenBoto">
              <a href="" class="btnionfo">Añadir al carrito</a>
              <a href="especifica.php?ID=<?php echo $tipos['id'] ?>" class="btnMasInfo">Ver información prueba</a>
            </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>

      <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

**JAVSCRIPT:**

```
$('#txtSearch').on('keyup',(e)=>{
      let contenedor = $('#contenedor');
      let search = $('#txtSearch').val();
      contenedor.children('.datos').each((i,e)=>{
       if($(e)[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())){
       $(e).css("display","")
       }else{
       $(e).css("display","none")
       }
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te sirva.

Lo que se me ocurre es quitar los caracteres como las tildes y diéresis:

```
$("#txtSearch").on("keyup", e => {
  let contenedor = $("#contenedor");

  let search = $("#txtSearch")
    .val()
    .trim()
    .toLocaleLowerCase()
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

  contenedor.children(".datos").each((i, e) => {
    let textoContenedor = $(e)[0]
      .innerText.trim()
      .toLocaleLowerCase()
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

    if (textoContenedor.includes(search)) {
      $(e).css("display", "");
    } else {
      $(e).css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Explicaré los cambios:
La función trim quita los espacios a los lados del texto, toLowerCase como ya sabes pone todo en minúsculas, y normalize especifico la forma de normalización Unicode (NFD Forma de Normalización de Descomposición Canónica), en el replace especifico un rango unicode, esto hace que un texto:

```
"Qué fue, pingüino, Jonás, ñame    "
```

a:

```
"que fue, pinguino, jonas, name"
```

Comment: wooww @jonasdamher funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias por tu solución!